# CSS positioning issues: invalid property value

Tags: html, css, position, padding

I have some very simple HTML/CSS code, and no matter what I do, I always get an "invalid property value" exception by chrome, and the logo won't position properly.

Fixed the first problem, but now the image does not move related to the border.

```
<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>my website</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        *{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }

        .header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            border: none;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-bottom-width: 5px;
            position: relative;
            border-bottom-color: rgb(220,30,60);
        }

        .logo {          
            position: absolute;
            padding-bottom:50px;
            height: 150%;
            width: auto;                
        }    
      
    </style>        
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header" id="header">
        <img id="logo" class="logo"  src="image.png"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `50 px` should be `50px`.

Comment: yeah, fixed it, but now that img won't move related to the bottom-border.  I thought, padding sets the distance to the border of the div?

Comment: @tagduck take a look at my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40489435/1076753

Comment: You should edit your question with the current version, and what else you are missing. If it's two separate questions, they should be asked in two separate posts. And this one should be closed, because a typo won't help anyone.

Comment: 1. Properly? I don't know what you are trying to do. 2. Add a JSfiddle.

Comment: @tagduck you used padding-bottom instead of bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just don't understand why you used **padding-bottom** instead of **bottom** in this case. Anyway:

```
   <html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>my website</title>
        <style type="text/css">
             *{ padding: 0; margin: 0; } 
            .header {
                position: relative;
                height: 100px;
                border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(220,30,60);
            }
            .logo {
                position: absolute;
                bottom:50px;
                height: 150%;
                width: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="header" id="header">
        <img id="logo" class="logo"  src="image.png"/>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS **bottom** property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp

CSS **padding-bottom** property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-bottom.asp

Comment: Thanks, bottom worked for me. Why shouldn't I use padding-bottom?

Comment: Because padding and position are two different properties.

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar issue for me.

I wrote `10` (instead of `10px`), this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using single quotes in your css, ***Please remove single quotes from  your css file.***

For Example

```
// Wrong
.row{
    margin-left:'-16px !important';
    margin-right:'0px !important';
}

// Right
.row{
    margin-left:-16px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a space before the `px` in `padding-bottom:50 px;`. Fix:

```
padding-bottom: 50px;
```